# Any good painting/drawing software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for new software to play around with, even though I love MyPaint. I've found that Krita is available from the Software Centre but I'm still looking for more options. I've been wanting to try out Paint Tool SAI, but haven't really bothered because it's only a trial and wasn't sure on how to install it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14):

I use KolourPaint for its resemblence to Paintbrush in Windows. I would rather call it the Paintbrush counterpart for Ubuntu!

[image: KolourPaint painting/drawing software]

Hope you like it too! It's gettable from the Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: I didn't like Pinta at all. This was the better tool for me. Very much mimics Paint in Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My favourite would be [Pinta Image Editor](http://pinta-project.com/). More details you can find on their website.

[image]

Of course, GIMP too. Hope you like it.

Comment: Simple enough to draw something quickly. Doesn't seem to support HiRes display well though since buttons tiny on 4K screen but still OK. Using latest 2.0.1 from snap.

Answer (score 4):

GIMP, best drawing, photo editing software there is, similar to photoshop, but completely free. its in the Software center just to let you know.

Comment: Just tried to draw/paint a rectangle ... well. Not successful :)

Comment: One way is to use the selection tool to select an rectangle - then choose from the menu 'edit' -> 'Stroke Selection'

Comment: Not the best for drawing for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try Krita, it has a lot of templates to choose from and is easy to use.
This can be found in the software centre. https://www.calligra.org/krita/

Answer (score 1):

I like to use gnome-paint for my drawings.